# SNMPv3 does not show all parameters

Tags: cisco, snmpv3

I configured SNMPv3 on my Cisco 1841 router. Then I added that router to my monitoring program.

The problem is: it shows only ICMP loss, ICMP ping, ICMP response time and SNMP agent availibility.
It does not show any other parameters like CPU utilization, interfaces status, system description, etc.
What can be the problem?

Here is my configuration:

```
snmp-server view all-access iso included
snmp-server group GROUP1 v3 auth read all-access
snmp-server user user1 GROUP1 v3 auth md5 password
```

When setting group, there is no `priv` parameter after v3. 
When setting user, there is no `des56` parameter after md5 password.

Comment: @Zac67, Cisco 1841

Comment: That is a crazy old router so I’m surprised it supports SNMPv3 at all, let alone the issues you’re seeing.  You might be better sticking with SNMPv2 and using an ACL to restrict access since SNMPv2 might give you more options.

Comment: @JesseP. thanks for your answer. Let me check that, then I will reply.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Certain things don’t show up in SNMP configurations- things like snmp user. Use the command `show snmp user` as for all of the settings- it is possible they are default and thus don’t show for brevity. You might find it under `show run all`